# Placing message on clustered queue

Tags: java, ibm-mq

We are trying to place message on IBM message clustered queue. When we place the message on the queue the following error will be thrown:

```
MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'.
```

When we try to place a message on a local queue on one of our queue managers it's working fine. But on a clustered queue it does not work.

```
MQQueue queue = null;
MQMessage mqMessage = null;

MQEnvironment.hostname = settings.getServer();
MQEnvironment.channel = settings.getChannel();
MQEnvironment.port = settings.getPort();

MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(settings.getQueueManager());

int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;

queue = queueManager.accessQueue(settings.getQueue(), openOptions);
```

Can someone help us with placing message on a clustered queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQRC `2085` is `MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME` which normally means the queue manager you are connected to can't find this queue either locally defined or via the cluster(s) it is a member of.

Another reason you get a `2085` is if you try to open a clustered queue for `INPUT` (`GET`).  You can only `OUTPUT` (`PUT`) to a clustered queue that is not located on the local queue manager.  If you remove `CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF` from your `openOptions` it should fix your problem.  Unrelated to your problem, it is good practice to always include `CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING` this will allow the queue manager to shutdown normally and not be held up by your process being connected.

```
int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
```

---

You can confirm if the queue manager you are connected too knows about this queue in its partial repository along with which cluster it is a member of and what cluster queue managers it is hosted on with the following command:

```
DIS QC(clustered_queue_name_here) CLUSTER CLUSQMGR
```

A partial repository only learns about a clustered queue the first time it is accessed so it may not show up until you fix your `openOptions` and try to access it again.